# Reading file async still blocks the UI

Tags: wpf, user-interface, asynchronous, block

I have a simple treeview, when click on treeview item i just load a text file

Here is the code:

```
private async void NotesTreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    var clickedModel = e.NewValue as TreeFileItem;
    if (clickedModel != null && File.Exists(clickedModel.FilePath))
    {
        _viewModel.NoteLoadingInProgress = true;
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(clickedModel.FilePath))
        {
            var fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            _viewModel.ActiveNote = fileContent;
        }
        _viewModel.NoteLoadingInProgress = false;
    }
}
```

This works, but when I click on treeview item the ui is frozen, until file read is complete. Why such behavior? I have other async methods in my code and they don't block ui.

**EDIT:** it seems the issue not in reading file, but in setting large amount of text to textbox.text properti via databinding, though setting it directly also take a lot of time and make ui freeze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the ui is frozen, until file read is complete

Streams opened with `File.OpenText` are never asynchronous. As I [describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/08/reminder-about-asynchronous-filestreams.html), you must open the file using a method with an `isAsync` parameter (set to `true`) or a `fileOptions` parameter (including the `FileOptions.Asynchronous` value).

> it seems the issue not in reading file, but in setting large amount of text to textbox.text properti via databinding

Yes, UI elements are not intended to be used with huge amounts of data. You need to use [virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx) if you have large amounts of data to display.

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunally TextBox is not in list of controls, that supports UI virtualization

Comment: @igorGIS: Then you'll have to build your own virtualization system, or use a text display that supports virtualization (IIRC there's some kind of document system).